# Predicting decision boundary on the basis of choosen hypothesis function

Tags: machine-learning

In Machine Learning course on coursera in Week-3 Andrew-Ng discusses about [Decision boundary](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/WuL1H/decision-boundary) and at 1:00 states that-

hθ(x)≥0.5 → y=1

(Hypothesis will predict y=1 if it's value is greater than or equal to 0.5)

hθ(x)<0.5 → y=0

(Hypothesis will predict y=0 if it's value is less than 0.5)

where hθ(x) is a sigmoid fumction of θtX.

Doubt-

If this is the case then Pr(y=1) will always be greater than or equal to 0.5 as y=1 is assumed to be predicted only when hθ(x)≥0.5 and this hθ(x) is considered to be the probability of y=1 as disscussed [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/RJXfB/hypothesis-representation) at 4:45.
Same is the case for Pr(y=0) which is assumed to be predicted when hθ(x)<0.5 and so it's value will always be less than 0.5.

But this shouldn't be the case, probabilities of y=0 and y=1 should range from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is a misunderstanding of what is being modeled and/or what probability of a dependent variable is.

First of all we are talking about **conditional** probabilities P(y|x), not marginals P(y), second of all:

```
h(x) = P(y=1|x) = 1-P(y=0|x)
```

there is no claim that "probability of P(y=0|x) is modeled when h(x)<0.5", this is false. This model provides both quantities at the same time, it predicts P(y=1|x) = h(x) and at the same time (due to basic properties of probabilities) P(y=0|x) = 1-h(x). This is also why we have the 0.5 threshold, as what you try to answer when class is predicted is **what is the most probable class**, and notice that:

```
P(y=1|x) > P(y=0|x) <-> h(x) > 1-h(x) <-> 2h(x) > 1 <-> h(x) > 0.5
```

It does not mean that probability of one class or another is "always bigger than 0.5" or always smaller - there is just one probability, being modeled by h(x), and 0.5 comes from the above equation to get final label, not its probability.

Answer (score 0):

I think the doubt is coming when you say probability of a class p(y=1) , we only calculate conditional probability for each class given data point x , also h(x)=0.5 means the equal chances for data point to be in one of the class and graphically represent the straight line partitioning the two classes.